# How to run integration tests of spring services triggered by a database change?

Tags: java, spring, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have a set of spring services that use a configuration database to change how they perform their tasks.

Whenever a change is made to that database I want to kick off integration tests that will test that the services are still working and that the changed configuration didn't break everything.

My idea is to make another spring service that will be called after a successful database change is made and can check if things are good to go (using Rest Assured to call the services, etc.).

I'm not sure if this is the right approach as I've never done something like this.

Looking for any alternative ideas or pretty much anything that could assist with this task.

Comment: One approach would be to have a CI server task occasionally poll the config tables.  If any detected change then kick a job to run the tests.  However, consider putting the database changes (in this case probably an UPDATE script) in source control to enable Continuous Database Integration.  This allows the data to be treated as important as the code.

Comment: We currently use liquibase for schema control and were looking into some tooling to assist with the data as well. The polling is a good idea. The only 'problem' is that it wouldn't be kicked off right away if something changed. Not that changes happen too often anyways. So it's not really a big issue. Would more be about someone wanting immediate validation.